# mod_rewrite is not working in vagrant

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, vagrant, vagrantfile, ubuntu-15.10

I am new to vagrant world :-)

Using **Ubuntu 15.10**,
**VirtualBox 5.0**,
**Vagrant 1.8.1** and Installed **precise32** box

In my box I have installed **Apache2**, **php5** and **mysql** as per need

**Loaded Modules:**

```
core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_ssl mod_status
```

**Enabled SSL**

**Vagrant VirtualHost ssl file**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /vagrant/www

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have tried to add the following code into my SSL VirtualHost but still in no luck :-(

```
<Directory "/vagrant/www">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Vagrantfile config:**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.7"
  config.vm.synced_folder "~/myvm/www", "/vagrant_data"
end
```

My homepage(index.php) is working fine but the inner pages aren't opening, please suggest how to config/enable **.htaccess** and **mod_rewrite** properly in vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

For **.htaccess**, you need to add the `AllowOverride` directive under a directory tag:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

That should do it.

**EDIT**

This may or may not help, but in 15.10 I believe the PPA version of apache is 2.4, which uses the `Require` directives:

```
<Directory "/vagrant/www">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow
   allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note the addition of **`Require all granted`**.

Comment: I have tried but not in luck, please see my revised question and guide me how can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: @zarpio updated my answer. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas!